# how to access a local variable value outside the scope of its function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to compare the data of two files and for that, I'm reading that file using the fs module but since I want to compare the values so I thought to store the value in an external variable but when I do console.log(budget_details) I get nothing in console. Please someone help. Please point me out if my approach is wrong and if we don't need to do that in nodejs. I'm new to nodejs.

```
import csv from 'csv-parser'
import fs from 'fs';

let budget_details
const budgetProcessing = (budget_file_path) => {
    try{
        fs.createReadStream(budget_file_path)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (row) => {
                budget_details = row
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
            });
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

budgetProcessing('budget.csv')

console.log(budget_details)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first explain why you don't get the expected result, it doesnt have to do with scope actually:

```
import csv from 'csv-parser'
import fs from 'fs';

let budget_details
const budgetProcessing = (budget_file_path) => {
    try{
        fs.createReadStream(budget_file_path)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (row) => {
                budget_details = row
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
            });
     }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

budgetProcessing('budget.csv')

console.log(budget_details)
```

`fs.createReadStream` is not itslef exactly asynchronous but then we pipe the returned stream to `csv-parser` which does event based parsing, so even if you call budgetProcessing before the `console.log(budget_details)` the stream reading has most likely not runned yet and `budget_details` is still undefined.

To fix this, you could move this `console.log(budget_details)` where it is set like so:

```
    let budget_details
    const budgetProcessing = (budget_file_path) => {
        try{
            fs.createReadStream(budget_file_path)
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', (row) => {
                    budget_details = row
                    console.log(budget_details)
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                     console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
                });
         }
         catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    budgetProcessing('budget.csv')
```

but then the variable itself wouldnt serve any real purpose so instead you could do this:

```
    const budgetProcessing = (budget_file_path, callback) => {
        try{
            fs.createReadStream(budget_file_path)
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', (row) => {
                    callback(row)
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                     console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
                });
                
         }
         catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    budgetProcessing('budget.csv', (budget_details) => {
        console.log(budget_details) // or anything with budget_details
    })
```

Lastly, I want to make clear that the callback will be called for each row of the csv as specified in [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser)'s documentation

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. You really helped me a lot. Just one more doubt is there any inbuilt asynchronous fs createReadStream module that will return a promise or do I have to create my own promise object if I don't want to use call back.

Comment: According to csv-parser github (https://github.com/mafintosh/csv-parser) there is a Promise based implementation at https://github.com/sindresorhus/neat-csv

Answer (score 1):

your code is not asynchronous. Anything with 'on', which takes a function, would indicate that it is event driven. You need something like:

```js
import csv from 'csv-parser'
import fs from 'fs';

let budget_details
const budgetProcessing = (budget_file_path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    fs.createReadStream(budget_file_path)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
        budget_details = row
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
        resolve()
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    reject(error)
  }
})

budgetProcessing('budget.csv')
  .then(() => console.log(budget_details))
```

Comment: Mark, but in the console.log I'm getting only one row instead of all the rows of CSV file.

Comment: budget_details should be initialised with empty string as `let budget_details = ''` and `budget_details = row` this part should be `budget_details += row`